# How to get the current view path in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, path

I need to pass the path for current view to a render for partial within that view in order to generate a link (in the partial) to the view itself. How can I get the path for the current view when javascript is disabled?

```
<%= render "errors", object: @car.plate, path: (what?)%>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what you actually need, one of these might help:
`request.url`, `request.path`

if you to know the controller/action being called:
`controller_name`, `action_name`

Comment: `request.path` is what I want. Thank you.

Comment: `controller_path` is the correct answer! on nested routes, request.path would return things like customer/1/articles but controller_path returns `articles` and thats where the view is.